# Simplify the sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

The exercise requires to simplify the following expression:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{25} \binom{50}{2k}$$

By finally looking at someone's answer, I know that the result should be $2^{49}$, but the following step was used along the way, and I didn't understand the logic behind it:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{25} \binom{50}{2k} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{50} \binom{50}{k}$$

Could you please kindly explain what is behind this equality? Thanks!

Comment: And the author of the answer did not say?

Comment: the answer was written many years ago :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! It was very helpful!!

Comment: "the answer was written many years ago" Which page was this?

Comment: What do you mean? I found the answer in a scanned notebook if that helps...

Comment: And the author of the answer in the scanned notebook did not explain why the solution was true?

Comment: I guess this step seemed obvious to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the $\binom{50}n$ is the number of subsets of size $n$ of a set of $50$ things. As $k$ runs from $0$ through $25$, $2k$ runs through the even numbers from $0$ through $50$. Thus, $\sum_{k=0}^{25}\binom{50}{2k}$ is the total number of even-sized subsets of a set of $50$ things. It’s a basic fact that if $S$ is a non-empty, finite set, exactly half of the subsets of $S$ have even cardinality, and the other half have odd cardinality. (If you’ve not seen this before, you should try to prove it.) A set of $50$ things has $\sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}k$ subsets altogether, and half of them have even cardinality, so

$$\sum_{k=0}^{25}\binom{50}{2k}=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}k\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

You know the expansion
$$
(1 + x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} x^i.
$$
Set $x = 1$ to get 
$$
2^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} =
\sum_{\text{$i$ even}} \binom{n}{i}
+ \sum_{\text{$i$ odd}} \binom{n}{i}.
$$
Then set $x = -1$ to get
$$
0 = \sum_{\text{$i$ even}} \binom{n}{i}
- \sum_{\text{$i$ odd}} \binom{n}{i},
$$
or
$$
\sum_{\text{$i$ even}} \binom{n}{i}
= \sum_{\text{$i$ odd}} \binom{n}{i}.
$$